# Hide auto fill icon in the Input component React strap

Tags: reactjs, input, autocomplete, field, reactstrap

I have a form in React using `react-strap` and render an input like the image below, I want to hide the contact icon at the end of the input
by many ways of using CSS but won't work.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<Form>
    <FormGroup row>
       <Label className="col-4 font-weight-bold">
         Name on Card
       </Label>
       <Col>
         <Input type="text" name="card" autoComplete="off" />
       </Col>
    </FormGroup>
</Form>
```

Comment: I've just created this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/44xn15wzw) and theres no icon

Comment: Or maybe reactstrap has some other dependencies?

Comment: the browser auto detect, I forgot to note that I'm using Chrome

Answer (score 0):

use `autoComplete={0}`, this worked for me in Google Chrome, Safari and Mozilla